# How to serialize private discriminated union cases of F# with Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: f#, json.net

When I have such a code below:

```
open Newtonsoft.Json
type Foo = Bar of string
let f = Bar "f"
printfn "%A" <| JsonConvert.SerializeObject(f)
```

Foo is successfully being serialized.

However if I make the constructor private :

```
open Newtonsoft.Json
type Foo = private Bar of string
let f = Bar "f"
printfn "%A" <|  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(f)
```

Then Newtonsoft.Json serializes the result as an empty object. How can I configure Newtonsoft.Json so that it can successfully serialize and deserialize private cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[<JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.Fields)>]
```

needs to be added on top of the type. So below code works fine:

```
open Newtonsoft.Json
[<JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.Fields)>]
type Foo =  private Bar of string
let f = Bar "f"
let s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(f)
let f2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(s)

printf "%A" f2
```