# F#: How to deserialize a private discriminated union with Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: json, f#

In [his question and answer from 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53675853/how-to-serialize-private-discriminated-union-cases-of-f-with-newtonsoft-json), [Onur Gumus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3388184/onur-gumus) used [<JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.Fields)>] to enable serialization/deserialization of a discriminated union with a private constructor.

For me, the serialization works as advertised, but deserialization produces this error: "*Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type FSI_0037+Foo. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute.*"

Does anyone know how to get the deserialization working? I don't want to switch to a class type if it can be avoided. However, I've tried figuring out where to place a JsonConstructor attribute without any luck. I also tried passing [a settings value](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) with the [ConstructorHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ConstructorHandling.htm) value set to AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor, but that changed nothing.

For convenience, I copy Onur's solution here:

```
open Newtonsoft.Json
[<JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.Fields)>]
type Foo =  private Bar of string
let f = Bar "f"
let s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(f)
let f2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(s)

printf "%A" f2
```

In case it matters (since things seem to have changed since 2018), I'm using .NET 5.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The code you supplied seems to work fine for me, printing out `Bar "f"`. What do I need to do to trigger the error you're seeing?

Comment: @brianberns, that was not the code with the problem.

Comment: Can you try to add the `[<CLIMutable>]` attribute before the type declaration? Also, would be nice to see the code that has trouble.

Comment: I believe you have stumbled onto a bug. I get this in one test, and not in another test, and the two tests are equal. I am investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am reasonably sure you have stumbled onto a bug.

When I copied the sample code you refer to into LINQPad v6.13.13, and ran it, then it worked fine. I then tried to replace the attribute with another attribute - the one I mentioned in the comment. Not unexpectedly that didn't compile. So I just reverted to the original attribute. Then I got the same compile error you encountered. That should not have happened. It's a bug. But where?

Further investigation has revealed that the compile error is produced erroneously if I do the following in LINQPad:

1. Open the code snippet from a file, and try to run it. This compiles and runs fine.
2. Comment out the attribute, and try to run it. This produces the compile error in question. This is as it should be.
3. Bring back the attribute, and try to run it. This should compile and run fine of course, since the source is now as it was in step 1, but it still produces the compile error in question.

Trying the same steps repeatedly will produce the same problem, whether I restart LINQPad between runs or not.

Then I tried to reproduce the problem with Visual Studio. I did not succeed - there is no such problem in VS 16.10.3

I have no more time at the moment, but will continue to investigate later. I want to check this with the latest LINQPad beta.

As for your question, was this the cause?

**UPDATE**

I have now checked with LINQPad v6.14.10, the current beta version. The bug is not present there. I am not surprised. As I've mentioned in a comment, the compiler is my prime suspect. Even more so because you tell you have the problem in VSCode. But there is an even more interesting detail.

LINQPad has used a very old version of the F# compiler service for ages, because there was a bug that prevented updating it. Joseph Albahari, the creator of LINQPad, recently got impatient waiting for a fix for this bug, and found a workaround. That fix is only in the beta. The huge leap in the F# compiler service version naturally means lots of bugs has been fixed, and likely this one too.

I am not going to pursue this further. I don't use VSCode, but if this problem is present even in the latest REPL there, then maybe somebody should look into it.

Comment: thanks so much for this analysis. I'm getting the issue in the fsi REPL in VS Code. Bizarrely, I tried it in LINQPad, and I actually can't seem to reproduce it there the way you did. So I set up a quick test project, and it worked as expected there as well. I suppose I don't _need_ it to work in the REPL as long as I can assume (hope?) it will work in development/production code.

Comment: Of course I'd love to hear it if anyone figures out the intermittent error, but this put me on the right track, so I'm accepting it. Thanks again, Bent!

Comment: The fact that you had the issue in VS Code, and not LINQPad as I did, means that we can rule out the IDE as the source of the problem. My prime suspect then is definitely the compiler, so I will file a report in dotnet/fsharp on GitHub.

Comment: I guess there is a similarity between the REPL and LINQPad, so that is perhaps a clue too.

Comment: Updated the answer with my latest and final findings.